# Change background color (Jquery? Css3?)

Tags: css, button

**UPDATE**

Update:

As following Zach Saucier instructions, added the following codes:

JS

```
this.onclick = function() { this.style.background = "red"; this.innerHTML = "Bought"; }
```

So the button is:

```
<a onclick="javascript:func(this)" class="ajax_add_to_cart_button comprar_mat" rel="ajax_id_product_14" href="../cart.php?add&amp;id_product=14" id="matricularme">Matricularme</a>
```

But still does not work

---

I am trying to add some effects on a few buttons in my website and I am not able to do it.

The HTML link (shown as button) looks like this:

```
<td class="marker">
    <a class="ajax_add_to_cart_button comprar_mat" rel="ajax_id_product_14" href="../cart.php?add&amp;id_product=14">Buy it now!</a>
</td>
```

As you can see this button adds a product on my website, and I just want to change the whole text to "Bought" text and replacing the background also.

What should I use? Any kind of Jquery? Or maybe just adding a css style where one sprite-image is "Buy it now!" and "Bought", so just change the background position?

Thanks

Comment: Most likely it'd be best to use javascript to do so. It'd require a click event, something like `this.onclick = function() { this.style.background = "red"; this.innerHTML = "Bought"; }`

Comment: Adding the event as shown in the example does not work (also adding the js on the file) // <a onclick="javascript:func(this)" class="ajax_add_to_cart_button comprar_mat" rel="ajax_id_product_14" href="../cart.php?add&amp;id_product=14" id="matricularme">Buy it now!</a>

Comment: Either that or using an `onclick` event for the anchor

Comment: Adding the event does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this HTML

```
<td class="marker">
    <a onclick="buy()" id="myid">Buy it now!</a>
</td>
```

Set this JS

```
function buy() { 
    var ele=document.getElementById("myid");
    ele.style.background = "red"; 
    ele.innerHTML = "Bought"; 
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rU7yd/)

Another version, incorporating the reusabilitysugested by Zach and the variable string handling:

```
<td class="marker">
    <a onclick="buy(this)" id="myid">Buy it now!</a>
</td>
<br>
<td class="marker">
    <a onclick="buy(this)" id="myid">Buy it as gift!</a>
</td>


function buy(ele) { 
    ele.style.background = "red"; 
    ele.innerHTML = ele.innerHTML.replace("Buy it", "Bought"); 
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rU7yd/2/)

Comment: It works perfect. Thank you very much (i can't upvote for not having enough reputation, so could anyone vote it as the best answer?)

Comment: Not that it matters much, but you can accept the answer. If you get an answer that you think that solves your issue, accept it (there is a checkmark aprox at the same place than the upvote- downvote buttons)

Comment: I'd recommend passing itself as a parameter so that the function can be reused (: http://jsfiddle.net/rU7yd/1/

Comment: Hey Zach, your answer comes closer to my needs, but what about when I am using it on two different buttons? I mean there are few with one ID (Buy it now!) and another ones with this text (Buy as gift!) and I want to change it also to (Bought as gift). Any clue? Because on your script there is not a value of the ID

Comment: @ZachSaucier yes, you are right, that would be more reusable !

Comment: @XaviAlsina Vals' update does a good job of doing what you want. If the texts are quite different from one another you could use an array (`var options = ["Buy it now!", "Buy as gift!"];`) and `if else` statements to determine what text needs to be replaced

Comment: The problem there is that I am lost on it, so maybe I should use two differents scripts on the same document? Because the "if else" statement you are talking about I dont know how to set it up on the same code. Could you provide me any Fiddle to see it in action?

Comment: @vals what about If i have got a List of buttons with "Buy it now!" and "Buy it as gift"? How could i assign a value to transform it into (Bought, or Bought as gift?) Seems like the HTML Ids are the same, and the function calling them are the same also.